# Issue with laravel - str_random

Tags: php, laravel, variables, random

I have this code to upload image with Laravel:

```
     public function store(Requests\ArticleRequest $request)
    {
        $article['photo']= 'http://nationaluasi.com/dru/content/hotelIcon.png';
        $file = array('image' => $request->file('image'));
        // setting up rules
        $rules = array('image' => 'required',); //mimes:jpeg,bmp,png and for max size max:10000
         // doing the validation, passing post data, rules and the messages
        $validator = Validator::make($file, $rules);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
        // send back to the page with the input data and errors
        $article['photo'] = null;

        }
        else {
    // checking file is valid.
        if ($request->file('image')->isValid()) {
        $destinationPath = public_path().'/images'; // upload path
        $extension = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension(); // getting image extension
        $article['photo']  = str_random(5).'.'.$extension; // renameing image
         $request->file('image')->move($destinationPath, $article['photo']); // uploading file to given path
         // sending back with message

         }
        else {

        }
  }



        $article = new Article($request->all());
        $article['key']= str_random(30);


        Auth::user()->articles()->save($article);

        Alert::success('nnn','Good job!')->persistent("Close");



        return redirect('auctions');
    }
```

so everything is fine with image upload but when I see my `/public/images` folder the image have name: `DiYhh.png` but in database is stored: `/tmp/phpVu3QOa`

Why, what is the probem?
Why dont store the same name in `image` column at database (`DiYhh.png`) instead /tmp/... ???

Comment: Where do you persist the change to the database? In your code snippet, you just set `$article['image']` to the filename but then you don't show where you actually save it.

Comment: I save this into article table - column image ...

Comment: Could you add that code to the question as well, please?

Comment: Thanks, I can see the problem now. I've written an answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you set the article to something first, and then you overwrite it. So when you do this:

```
$article['photo']  = str_random(5).'.'.$extension;
$request->file('image')->move($destinationPath, $article['photo']);
```

you're successfully moving the file to the right place. But then a few lines further down, you do this:

```
$article = new Article($request->all());
```

and now, the code has forgotten that `$article['photo']` contains the filename you wanted - because it's been overwritten.

I would suggest moving the new article line further to the top, then make the changes on that object, and finally saving it once you've verified everything.

Comment: Now I got error: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'photo' cannot be null

Comment: Well, you do have to set the photo variable afterwards again. For instance: `$article = new Article($request->all());` then `$article->photo = $filename;`, then finally `$article->save();` to persist it. That assumes you've set the filename, and you could put other lines in-between as you'd like.